# comparing two list of lists with unequal size of each element list

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, list, nested-lists

I have two lists of lists that I am working on:
`L=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
 A=[[1,2],[4,5]]`
I want to compare L with A such that the following outputs should be appended in a separate list `K=[3,6]`
This function should check the first row of list A i.e. [1,2] with the first two elements of the row of list L i.e. [1,2] and if they are equal, the third element of the row in List L will be stored in a separate list K. Can someone give a working code or at least point me in the correct direction?

So far I've come up with this :

```
k=[]
for i in range(len(L)):
    if A[i][0]==l[i][0] and A[i][1]==L[i][1]:
        k.append(L[i][2])
```

The error that I am getting is "IndexError: list index out of range"

## Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far ?

Comment: also, there is undefined behavior in the current version of your question...by example, can any row in `L` match any row `A`? As an alternative, only row `L[i]` could match `A[i]`, if not skip to `A[i+1]`. This is not clear from your example and explanation.

Comment: k=[]
for i in range(len(A)):
     for j in range(len(A)):
             if A[i][j]==L[i][j] and A[i][j+1]==L[i][j+1]:
print k                     k.append(L[i][j+2])

Comment: The error I'm getting is "IndexError: list index out of range". I know the index goes out of range in the if statement. Please suggest something.

Comment: What about L[2] ? What should it match with ?

Comment: The elements of A will be compared with each element of L. So for this case, L[2]=[7,8,9]. Every element of A will be compared to every element of L. Here, A[0] and A[1] are both not equal to the first two elements of the rows L[2] and L[3].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should achieve what you are looking for (its bit sloppy to use len() and you might encounter an error if your lists vary in length)

```
L=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
A=[[7,8],[4,5]]
K=[]
for x in range(len(A)):
    for y in range(len(L)):
        if A[x] == L[y][:2]:
            K.append(L[y][2])
print K
out: [9, 6]
```

Comment: This code does not work for the following case :
L=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
A=[[7,8],[10,11]]
In this case, output list K should be [9,12] but it comes out to be an empty list because it only checks with the first two elements of L. Can you please fix that?

Comment: I created a seperate loop which solves your problem. If you have multiple lists in L with the same two front integers, then both of their third elements will be appened.